# LDAP authentication apache 2.2 error 500

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, ldap, apache-2.2

This is my LDAP configuration in Apache2.2.x

```
  Order deny,allow
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Test"
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc1.domain.com:389/DC=domain,DC=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "secret"
  authzldapauthoritative Off
  require valid-user
```

When I load the page, I get the pop up for password and username. But when I fill them in i get an internal server error.

If I look in the error log of apache is see no new errors. If I change my BindPassword to something wrong I get errors in my /var/log/apache2/error.log

Pulling my hair out!

Comment: Are you trying to load a simple page? What if there's a CGI script / webapp that would give HTTP 500 even if the authentication works?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652982/setting-up-apache-and-subversion-to-use-ldap-windows-active-directory-group-au

The problem that I had was that the port needed to be 3268.

Answer (score 0):

The only you need:

```
        <Location /> <!-- you can change the location if you want -->
            AuthType basic
            AuthName "Your popup title"
            AuthBasicProvider ldap
            AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
            AuthLDAPURL ldap://dc1.domain.com:389/DC=domain,DC=com?sAMAccountName
            require valid-user
        </Location>
```